# ResourceBundleMessageSource cant find my local

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization

## My Situation

I want to use ResourceBundleMessageSource in my project (Maven/SpringBoot). But I dont get it to work and found no other help online.

### The Error

**o.s.c.s.ResourceBundleMessageSource      : ResourceBundle [resources/label] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name resources/label, locale de_DE**

### My Data:

---

in my configurations.java:

```java
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasenames("Resources");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }
```

---

My App.java:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

---

My structure is:

```
Main
|
|App.java (to Start the App)
|Resources
\
 | "locale de_DE.properties"
```

---

Comment: afaik a bundle called 'Foo' ahould be name Foo_de_DE.properties. You'd call `getBundle("Foo")`

Comment: Your structure doesn't make sense, nor I suspect that your file is named `Resources_de_DE.properties` which is what you should have named them. As you are using Spring Boot I would strongly sugest to ditch your `messageSource` bean. and name your file `messages.properties` and `messages_de_DE.properties` and have the default configured `MessageSource` by Spring Boot do its work.

Comment: @M.Deinum: My file was call "locale de_DE.properties". I did was you suggested, removed the bean and put files messages.properties and messages_de_DE.properties in my resource package. No I get an **No message found under code 'ER_USER_EXISTS' for locale 'de_DE'.** exception. My messagefile has just 1 entry: **ER_USER_EXISTS=#### User existiert schon.**. I look around to solve this and Iam thankfull for your guidance, this is my first ever project with Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different files with names appending the locale.
`en_US` or `ja_JP` or `de_DE`
The files will look like below.
`messages.properties` --> Default
`messages_de_DE.properties`
`messages_en_US.properties`

This should fix the problem. In your ResourceBundle you can pass the locale.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake thanks to @M.Deinum.

### Solution

---

1. I removed the Bean.
2. Renamed the file  `messages.properties`  and made a second one for german.
3. Put these files in src\resources.

---

No it works fine.